# Login in as root in Debian on an AWS instance

Tags: ssh, debian, root

As the title says, I want to Login in as root in Debian on an AWS instance. I have tried various methods as described in [this](https://blog.tiger-workshop.com/enable-root-access-on-amazon-ec2-instance/), [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174558/is-allowing-root-login-in-ssh-with-permitrootlogin-without-password-a-secure-m) and others.

In other words I have set:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.  I also changed the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file for root as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840684/989468).  However, I am still not able to login - I get Access Denied.

I realize this is not best practice but I am doing this on a learning server to better understand security and see if I can implement something experimental.

Comment: Did you restart sshd after you made the changes to sshd_config?

Comment: Yes.  sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload  (I tried sudo /etc/init.d/sshd reload but it said no such command).